# get results of terminated map_async of multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am running a script with multiprocessing `map_async`. what I need to do is to get the uncomplete result of AsyncResult object (assuming it already finished calculating some of the cases given) after terminating Pool with `terminate()`. using `get()` would just hang the script, how can I do this?

I know this can be done with `apply_sync` with some manipulation, but can it be done somehow with `map_async`?

working example of the situation:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
def example_run(i):
    time.sleep(0.7)
    return i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    terminate = False
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
    result_async = pool.map_async(example_run,range(100))
    i = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1.0)
        if i == 70:
            terminate = True
        print(result_async.ready(),terminate)
        if result_async.ready():
            break
        elif terminate:
            pool.terminate()
            break
        i += 10
    result = result_async.get() # The problem is here, it will just wait
    print(result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem; with some digging, `AsyncResult._value` seem to hold the values of the execution, with None in case it is not evaluated yet

```
import multiprocessing
import time
def example_run(i):
    time.sleep(0.7)
    return i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    terminate = False
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
    result_async = pool.map_async(example_run,range(100))
    i = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1.0)
        if i == 70:
            terminate = True
        print(result_async.ready(),terminate)
        if result_async.ready():
            break
        elif terminate:
            pool.terminate()
            break
        i += 10
    result = []
    for value in result_async._value:
        if value is not None:
            result.append(value)
        else:
            result.append("failed")
    print(result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```